# Computing $P(Y > 3X \mid Y > 0)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. standard normal

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

How can I compute $P(Y > 3X \mid Y > 0)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. standard normal? The solution that I have is pretty unclear to me:

"The key is that $N(0, 1)^2$ is cyclically symmetric. When plotting the distributions, the p.d.f. will be cyclically symmetric about the origin. Then, one can perform a geometric probability calculation to obtain an answer in terms of $\arctan$".

I'm pretty confused, and I'm wondering if someone can please explain the solution. I tried using Bayes' Rule, which led me nowhere. I don't quite see how to visualize $N(0, 1)^2$, or even how it's related to the problem.

I just drew this picture in Desmos for reference:

[image]

Comment: Hint: draw a graph of this event.

Comment: I know how to draw normal distributions, but how can I draw the distribution of $Y$ since we have the additional information that $Y > 0$? Does the center just shift so that everything's positive (that seems wrong to me intuitively)?

Comment: The event is defined without reference to the distribution: it consists of the set of all $(x,y)$ in the plane for which $y \gt 3x$ and $y \gt 0.$

Comment: Re the picture: you must include the entire second quadrant as well.

Comment: Oops. I just updated it again. Why are we looking at a circle?

Comment: See [the Wolfram Alpha site's rendering of the distribution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Heaviside%28y%29+Heaviside%28y+-+3x%29+exp%28-x%5E2%2F2+-+y%5E2%2F2%29+%2F+%282+pi%29%2C++x%3D-3..3%2C+y%3D-3..3)  Your quotation explains why the contours of the probability density are concentric circles around the origin.

Comment: This was also asked here sometime back: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3671399/321264.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: *draw* (preferably on a piece of paper) a sketch of a circle centered at the origin. Mark (by shading) the region corresponding to the event $(Y > 0)$.  Then, mark (by cross-hatching) the *sub*-region corresponding to the event $(Y >0)\cap Y > 3X)$. What *fraction* of the region $(Y > 0)$ is the region $(Y >0)\cap Y > 3X)$?

Comment: I just drew the picture with Desmos and updated my original post with the change. Is this image correct? Also, why are we looking at a circle centered at the origin?

Comment: @Wan What about the region corresponding to the event $Y > 0$?

Answer (score 0):

The key point is about the circular symmetry in this particular case, a property of using a standard multivariate normal distribution which has the joint density $\frac1{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$, so all points of equal radius from the origin have the same $x^2+y^2$ and so the same density.

The graph below shows a sample of $10000$ points and it illustrates this.  You are then trying to find the probability that a particular point is coloured red given that it is red or pink, and the circular symmetry means this is just a ratio of angles

[image]

R code for this

```
set.seed(2020)
X <- rnorm(10000)
Y <- rnorm(10000)
rpbg <- ifelse(Y > 0, ifelse(Y > 3*X, "red", "pink"),
                      ifelse(Y > 3*X, "black", "grey")) 
plot(X, Y, col=rpbg)
```